# plugin msi not removing previous(older) version of plugin

Tags: plugins, wix, firebreath

```
<?define myvar="C:\Documents and Settings\rohit\Desktop\plugin"?>
  <?define search_accel="My search accelerator_5_0_0_0"?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="My Plugin" Language="1033" Version="7.0.0.0" Manufacturer="My Technologies Pvt. Ltd." UpgradeCode="{789344f3-6ced-5a92-aa44-51f3694c207f}">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" Description="Installer for the MyPlugin plugin" InstallScope="perUser" />

    <Upgrade Id="{789344f3-6ced-5a92-aa44-51f3694c207f}">
        <UpgradeVersion
            Property="OLD_VERSION_FOUND"
            Minimum="0.0.1" IncludeMinimum="yes"
            Maximum="7.0.0.0" IncludeMaximum="yes"
            OnlyDetect="no" IgnoreRemoveFailure="yes"
            MigrateFeatures="yes" />
    </Upgrade>

    <Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" />
        <InstallExecute After="RemoveExistingProducts" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyPlugin.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
```

This is my **.wxs** file.
Now I'm upgrading to plugin version 7.0. Previous version was 6.2!

But when i try to install new plugin without removing previous one, the new plugin(v7.0) gets installed along with plugin v6.2.

I want the old plugin to get removed.

Is it something to do with GUID or some .wxs file configuration?

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/114786/1140783

Answer (score 0):

The above approach works for UPGRADE.

My problem was solved when I changed the GUID to what was expected. It had got changed due to moving my solution to diffrent machine and hence the different Visual-studio.