# WiX creating duplicate records in ARP when I change the version number

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

My WiX installer does not uninstall previous version record in ARP when I change the version number. It installs the updated files, but I end up with duplicate records in ARP. Does this have something to do with minor versus major upgrades? The beginning of my WiX installer file is as follows:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product Id="*" Name="Blah" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.6" Manufacturer="Blah Inc." UpgradeCode="c6044fe4-e07a-4dd0-9540-cc77b4430466">
<Package Id ="*" Keywords="Installer" Description="Blah Installer" Manufacturer="Blah Inc." InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" />

<Property Id="OLDVERSION" Secure="yes" />

<Upgrade Id="7BDF86F7-C6A8-4112-9DA6-FDFB6864AE66">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Minimum="1.0.0.0" Maximum="99.0.0.0" Property="OLDVERSION" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" />
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts Overridable="no" After="InstallInitialize"  />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Also, I realize this is somewhat of a duplicate question, however, the other has no WiX code and was never truely answered. Changing the third number of the version number changes nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

1. Is the Upgrade ID same for both MSI's? **The MSI wont know that there is a related product installed unless the upgrade GUID's are same.**
2. Looks like you have updated only the last digit of the version number? **if your version 1 uses Version value 1.0.1.0, then version 2 should have a Version value of 1.0.2.0 or higher (1.0.1.1 will not work here).**

From Wix3.5, there is a new element called MAJORUPGRADE [MajorUpgrade](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/01/16/major-upgrades-now-easier-than-ever/) which consolidates the lines which you have written and makes things easier. Can you make use of that and see if it works? Here is a link to Bob Arnsons blog introducing "MajorUpgrade" [MajorUpgrade](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2010/01/16/major-upgrades-now-easier-than-ever/)

Check this link for more details: [How to implement major upgrade](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The upgrade ID is the same for both. Also I did quit using the 4th digit of the version number, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Check the answer for the edits about "MajorUpgrade" element. can you try that?

Comment: MajorUpgrade is the way to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your **Upgrade Code** must generally be stable across versions to identify the products in question as related. They seem to differ in your code.

Furthermore you must implement a [**major upgrade**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114165/how-to-implement-wix-installer-upgrade?lq=1) to ensure that the old product version is uninstalled before the new one is installed. Otherwise you will get multiple installations showing up in ARP.

For good measure always **uppercase your GUIDs**, though I believe WIX will do this for you on compile. And make sure you uninstall all versions of your application before you try anything else.